# Raspberry PI 4 RPi.GPIO library doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: raspberry-pi, libraries

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 4GB, but using RPi.GPIO library on my code Terminal shows to me this message:

"GPIO.setup(INT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!"

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # use GPIO numbering
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
print('RPi.GPIO:',GPIO.VERSION)

INT = 12    # GPIO-12 button interrupt to shutdown procedure

# use a weak pull_up to create a high
GPIO.setup(INT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def main():

     while True:
      # set an interrupt on a falling edge and wait for it to happen
      GPIO.wait_for_edge(INT, GPIO.FALLING)
      # we got here because the button was pressed.
      # wait for 3 seconds to see if this was deliberate
      sleep(3)
      # check the button level again
      if GPIO.input(INT) == 0:
      # still pressed, it must be a serious request; shutdown Pi
          subprocess.call(['poweroff'], shell=True, \
          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

I can't found the mistake of the code, Is there any problem between Ubuntu and this library?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is your user allowed to access to GPIO? If not you have to do first `sudo adduser username gpio`

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much!